# Some Java helps with the Android source please?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, abstract-class, android-source

For here the Android source of [Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java).

In particular, the `setContentView()` method at line 1646:

```
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    getWindow().setContentView(layoutResID);
}
```

**i would like to find out what it is exactly calling/doing.**

Here is my trace ...

At line 642, we know it is of type [`android.view.Window`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/view/Window.java)

```
private Window mWindow;
```

But [Window.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/view/Window.java) is an abstract class. And at line 738, the method is abstract also:

```
public abstract void setContentView(int layoutResID);
```

**Where is the actual function body be implemented?**

Back to the [Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) file, at line 3746, we find some initializations of `mWindow`:

```
mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(this);
mWindow.setCallback(this);
...
```

Well, about [`com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PolicyManager.java)'s `makeNewWindow()`:

```
public static Window makeNewWindow(Context context) {
    return sPolicy.makeNewWindow(context);
}
```

and

```
private static final IPolicy sPolicy;
Class policyClass = Class.forName(POLICY_IMPL_CLASS_NAME);
sPolicy = (IPolicy)policyClass.newInstance();
```

[IPolicy.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/IPolicy.java) is an interface, which means no implementation at all.

**My trace cannot go any further. Would you please help me out?**

In particular, i know `Activity.setContentView()` will eventually call [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java)'s `Fragment.onInflate()` - line 920, `Fragment.onAttach()` - line 928, `Fragment.onCreate()` - line 953, `Fragment.onCreateView()` - line 967, and `Fragment.onViewCreated()` - line 991.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Where is the actual function body be implemented?**

```
private Window mWindow;
```

The mWindow is initialized by :

```
mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(this);
```

in the attach() method. Look at the PolicyManager.makeNewWindow method in PolicyManager.java.

```
Class policyClass = Class.forName(POLICY_IMPL_CLASS_NAME);
sPolicy = (IPolicy)policyClass.newInstance();

public static Window makeNewWindow(Context context) {
    return sPolicy.makeNewWindow(context);
}
```

And the `POLICY_IMPL_CLASS_NAME` is `com.android.internal.policy.impl.Policy`. So look at the Policy.java. Here it is:

```
public Window makeNewWindow(Context context) {
    return new PhoneWindow(context);
}
```

And the `setContentView` is implmenented in the `PhoneWindow.java`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Let me add the links of `com.android.internal.policy.impl.Policy` and `com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow` [2.2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/policies/base/+/froyo-release/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl) | [2.3.5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.3.5_r1/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl).