# Android source code, Java trace, abstract class

Tags: java, android, abstract-class, android-source, android-fragmentactivity

**i would like to find out what exactly the [Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)'s `setContentView()` method is calling/doing.**

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) is the Android source code and the code stub at line 1646:

```
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    getWindow().setContentView(layoutResID);
}
```

Here is my trace ...

At line 642, we know it is of type [`android.view.Window`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/view/Window.java)

```
private Window mWindow;
```

But [Window.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/view/Window.java) is an abstract class. And at line 738, the method is abstract also:

```
public abstract void setContentView(int layoutResID);
```

**Where is the actual function body be implemented?**

Back to the [Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) file, at line 3746, we find some initializations of `mWindow`:

```
mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(this);
mWindow.setCallback(this);
...
```

Well, about [`com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PolicyManager.java)'s `makeNewWindow()`:

```
public static Window makeNewWindow(Context context) {
    return sPolicy.makeNewWindow(context);
}
```

and

```
private static final IPolicy sPolicy;
Class policyClass = Class.forName(POLICY_IMPL_CLASS_NAME);
sPolicy = (IPolicy)policyClass.newInstance();
```

[IPolicy.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/IPolicy.java) is an interface, which means no implementation at all.

**My trace cannot go any further. Would you please help me out?**

In particular, i know `Activity.setContentView()` will eventually call [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java)'s `Fragment.onInflate()` - line 920, `Fragment.onAttach()` - line 928, `Fragment.onCreate()` - line 953, `Fragment.onCreateView()` - line 967, and `Fragment.onViewCreated()` - line 991.

Comment: "In particular, i know Activity.setContentView() will eventually call android.support.v4.app.Fragment.java's Fragment.onInflate()" -- no, it will not. `Activity` knows nothing about `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. `Activity` may know something about `android.app.Fragment`. `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` may know something about `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Yes @CommonsWare, you are right. In fact, according to the source code, `Fragment.onAttach()`, `Fragment.onCreate()`, `Fragment.onCreateView()` and `Fragment.onViewCreated()` are called in `FragmentActivity.onCreate()` > `mFragments.dispatchCreate()` > `FragmentManager.moveToState(Fragment.CREATED, false)`. But surprisingly i added some `System.out.println()`s before and after `setContentView()`, and in those `Fragment` methods. It appears those `Fragment` methods are called within `setContentView()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some Java helps with the Android source please?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764572/some-java-helps-with-the-android-source-please)

Answer (score 0):

You can find this sources here

Policy implementation: [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/Policy.java#Policy.makeNewWindow%28android.content.Context%29)

Window implementation: [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#PhoneWindow.setContentView%28int%29)